# asyncio loop blocking django http and websocket requests

Tags: python, django, multithreading, python-asyncio, django-channels

i've been trying to build application where i need to listen to the postgres notify listen constantly and send those messages via websocket and also need the usual django apis, i'm able to run both separately, but as initiate the db listener it starts blocking http or websocket requests

```
connection = get_db_conn()
connection.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute("LISTEN new_item_added;")

async def db_listen():
    print('Started Listening to DB notify ...')
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        data = await queue.get()
        await NotificationConsumer.send_data(data.payload) # class method to send over websocket
        print("message received: ", data.payload)

def listen_callback():
    connection.poll()
    queue.put_nowait(connection.notifies.pop(0))

# calling this function from django app's __init__.py file
def initiate_db_listener():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.add_reader(connection, listen_callback)
    loop.run_until_complete(db_listen())
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    initiate_db_listener()
```

i tried many variations of it, all are blocking the main thread

Comment: Web servers spin their own event loops. Do not create a new loop, use a running one from the app. I am not sure about django, but in fastapi there is not even a need to do this explicitly: most use cases of this are covered in FastAPI.on_event. I suggest you search for a similar thing in django

Comment: @user15681262 makes sense, thanks for the direction, not sure if Django gonna have something like that, also now I’m able to run both loops with 2 threads but now both threads aren’t talking to each other properly